Does the Festival Lead ability let you use a TM attack twice?
Several Pokemon from the set Twilight Masquerade have the ability Festival Lead:

[Ability] Festival Lead
If Festival Grounds is in play, this Pokemon may use an attack it has twice. If the first attack Knocks Out your opponent's Active Pokemon, you may attack again after your opponent chooses a new Active Pokemon.

I'd like to know if this ability allows a Pokemon to use an attack from an attached Pokemon Tool, such as Technical Machine: Evolution:

Technical Machine: Evolution
The Pokémon this card is attached to can use the attack on this card. (You still need the necessary Energy to use this attack.) If this card is attached to 1 of your Pokémon, discard it at the end of your turn.
[C] Evolution
Choose up to two of your Benched Pokemon. For each of those Pokemon, search your deck for a card that evolves from that Pokemon and put it onto that Pokemon to evolve it. Then, shuffle your deck.

Can you use an attack from an attached Technical Machine twice in a single turn with the Festival Lead ability?

Per this Compendium ruling, the answer is no:

If I have a Technical Machine attached to a Pokemon that has the "Festival Lead" Ability, can I attack with the TM twice?


No, Festival Lead does not work with TM's; it has to be an attack that the Pokemon has printed on the card.

This is because the text refers to "an attack it has", which has been interpreted to meaning an attack printed on that card.  This is separate from the text of Cramorant (Lost Origins):

Ability Lost Provisions
If you have 4 or more cards in the Lost Zone, ignore all Energy in this Pokémon’s attack costs.

That does include TMs.  "This Pokémon's attacks" are considered to include anything the Pokémon can choose as an attack, while "Attack it has" does not.
This is self-consistent with rulings on Forest Seal Stone for example when an ability blocking effect is in place, such as Path to the Peak, Iron Thorns ex, or similar - for example, from this compendium ruling:

Can I use Forest Seal Stone's "Star Alchemy" Ability if Path to the Peak is in play?


Yes, you can. It's not an Ability the Pokemon has, but it's an Ability the Pokemon has access to.

